# Strange jQuery("checkbox").click().is(":checked") behavior

Tags: jquery, click, checked

Can anyone explain why `$(this).is(":checked")` gives the opposite result when the checkbox is clicked with `$("#test").click()` than when clicked manually or with `document.getElementById("test").click()` ??

EDIT Requested behavior here - thanks:

http://jsfiddle.net/ub8Zk/4/

EDIT 2

This has been driving me nuts, but I finally realize -- in version 1.5.2 of jQuery the event handler for the `change` event is fired when `click()` method is called (like native js)!! Not so in previous versions.

Look here:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6996564/jquery_click_test/test-1.4.4.htm
... test-1.5.1.htm
... test-1.5.2.htm

Can someone help me report this bug??

Comment: jsfiddle for editing fun: http://jsfiddle.net/ub8Zk/

Comment: Thanks for showing me jsfiddle, that's brilliant :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The click event happens **BEFORE** the value changes, so it is getting the **old** value. The the default handler for click happens AFTER your click event and toggles the value.  That is why it is getting the opposite value.  I would think the document click function is doing something wierd (I would not trust it, I would trust jQuery).

Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ub8Zk/4/

Comment: This is interesting, however, it is useless as long as it's the other way around when actually clicking the checkbox with the mouse! Any ideas? I need it to have the same value when executing the click handler in either case.

Comment: Oh, you actually changed my code to make it work! Thanks! Now I only need to understand the real difference between `.change()` and `.click()` when applied to checkboxes.

Comment: As I've written in the edit of my first post, there is a (supposed) bug in jQuery 1.5.2 that makes the change handler fire when the click method is called...

Comment: it looks like the `.change()` in the  `.click().change()` is the part that solves this (I just encountered this same problem). This seems like a bug in jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using a checkbox input, you want `is(':checked')` not `is(':selected')`

Comment: Also the click event happens BEFORE the value changes, so it is getting the old value, the the default handler for `click` happens and toggles the value

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that is just an error in the post. See the demo.

Comment: As I wrote below, how can this be practical? The same handler then has a different environment when triggering the click event with jQuery vs. manually!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input#someCheckbox').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // checked
    } else {
       // not checked
    };
});
```

Comment: Seems jQuery's developers could/should combine this into some kind of shorthand.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see your code. click() binds according to documentation a handler to the mouse click event. You may also write:$('#foo').bind('click', function() {
  alert('User clicked on "foo."');
});
If you want to trigger use the trigger() function like so: $('foo').trigger('click') or document.getElementById('foo').checked = true; when using straight javascript.

Comment: `.bind('click', function(){...})` is equivalent to `.click(function(){..})` and `.trigger('click')` is equivalent to `.click()`. I don't think this answer will help.